# Need help fixing my nginx server

Tags: node.js, nginx

My console looks like this

[image: Console Output]

This is my nginx cors setup

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://beloveddais.com';        
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

              if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://beloveddais.com';
                 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
                 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
                 add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                 add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                 add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                 return 204;
              }


             proxy_redirect off;
             proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

my node server looks like this

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {

  if('GET' == req.method){ 
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://beloveddais.com');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  }

  if('POST' == req.method){ 
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://beloveddais.com');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  }

 if('OPTIONS' == req.method){ 
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://beloveddias.com');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
   res.sendStatus(200); 
 }

next();
```

On my browser console I have been getting multiple headers, only one accepted. How do I fix this? I really need someone to help me out.

Comment: Either add headers on NGINX level or add it on your code, not both the places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should only contain one value as the allowed origin or you can use * to allow all origins.

As @TarunLalwani commented, you are adding `http://beloveddais.com` as a value to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header both in your NGINX configuration and in your code for the `OPTIONS` requests:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://beloveddais.com';
```

AND

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://beloveddias.com');
```

Remove one of them depending on your choice of design and it should be ok.